# Next Js app deployed on Vercel connected to a Mongodb database writes datas but displays the old datas at the time of deployment

Tags: mongodb, next.js, vercel

I've developped an app with Next Js that works perfectly fine on local dev server. It is connected to a MongoDB database. Datas are created, updated, deleted and read properly. The components refresh with the datas on the database. All good.
After deployment on Vercel, I can write datas, the website seems to work properly. Authentification works, redirection works. Everything works except that the datas read are the one that was on the database at deployment time, not the real, fresh datas recently inserted.
I've integrated MongoDB on Vercel, redeployed etc...still the same.

How comes that datas can be written but not read ? Nothing in the logs indicate a problem. Any suggestion??

Thank you.

Redeployment, reload of the entire project on Vercel,re-integration of MongoDB with Vercel.